# Circular Frame For Hist2D?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am making a 2D histogram of some data, for which the x-y coordinates are enclosed by a circle of radius 3.

```
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=200, weights=m)
```

It would be nice to render this plot with a circular frame rather than a square one, as obviously the corners contain no information.

I realise that a "circular" plot is similar to matplotlib's polar class, but for that I would need to redefine the histogram, in polar bins rather than Cartesian ones. Thus, I would like to change the shape of the frame without changing the data.

I will not necessarily need axis labels at all for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself.

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10000)
a = 3 * np.cos(t)
b = 3 * np.sin(t)

plt.subplot(1,1,1, frameon=False, aspect='equal')
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=200, weights=m)
plt.plot(a, b, 'k')
plt.xlim((-3.1, 3.1))
plt.ylim((-3.1, 3.1))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```